# H.265 support in the VSE?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor

Will we be able to edit 4k H.265 footage in the VSE in a near future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies but actually it seems that one is able to edit 4k H.265 footage in the VSE, am I right? I was able to bring in 4k H.265 footage in the vse without any convertion and do a soft cut at least.

Comment: which codec do you use and how did you install it? This would be useful for other users.

Comment: converting isn't that much of a problem, you can use ffmpeg or handbrake if blender won't let u input it. If the colour bits of your h.265 are only 8 bit and ur worried about artifacts you can just upscale to 16 bit png or something and input that into blender. The problem though is you STILL can't output it as h.265 in blender anyways...but u can just export it back out as ur png and do it in ffmpeg or handbrake which is just ffmpeg with a gui.